# How to print XML Schema

Tags: java, xsd

i would like to ask, how to print a xml schema. I creating my xsd schema on runtime and for testing i would like to see the generated xml schema. At the moment i working with `org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema` and i doesnt find anything how can print the xml schema.

Did anyone know how to print out (`System.out`) my `XmlSchema`??

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();  
       try {  
           String outputString = outputter.outputString(loXMLDoc);
       }
```

loXMLDoc is Dom for XML schema

Comment: might use a pretty format: 
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());

Comment: i dont know what about with me, i doesnt see the methode write(OutputStream) in org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema. This method is exactly what i need.

  **xmlSchema.write(System.out);**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XmlSchema 2.0

```
XmlSchema schema = ...
...
schema.write(System.out)
```

If you are using XmlSchema 1.x

```
XmlSchema schema = ...
...
schema.write(System.out, null)
```

Also, if you want to write to a string

```
StringWriter schemaWriter = new StringWriter();
schema.write(schemaWriter);
String schemaString = schemaWriter.toString();
```